# Data is not populated in the grid after the ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jsgrid

I am trying to use js grid for my application. I am trying to populate the grid after ajax request but it do not seem to work as expected.

I am trying with SQL Server as back end and web application is asp.net MVC

This is my code in the html

```
var table;
        var result;
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(document).ready(function () {

            table = $j('#grid').jsGrid({
                height: "60%",
                width: "50%",
                inserting: true,
                editing: true,
                sorting: true,
                paging: true,
                autoload: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                controller: {
                    loadData: function (filter) {
                        var d = $j.Deferred();
                         $j.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            url: "@Url.Action("LoadData", "User")",
                            datatype: "json",
                            data: filter
                            @*success: function (data) {
                                result = data.data;
                                console.log("result", result);
                                d.resolve(result)
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Error", "Audit")';
                            }*@
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            console.log("response", data);
                            console.log("data.data", data.data);
                            d.resolve(data)
                            });
                        return d.promise();

                    },
                    fields: [
                        { name: "LastName", type: "text"},
                        { name: "FirstName", type: "text"},
                        { name: "Email", type: "email"},
                        { name: "PhoneNumber", type: "number"},
                        { type: "control" }
                    ]
                }
            });
        });
```

In Controller I return

```
''return Json(new { data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);''
```

I expect the json data to bind in the div. But it did not ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should try to use "GET" instead POST ?

Comment: Not Working. How does js grid bind data here?

Comment: First of All you have to be sure that the data are getting from controller. Btw , what do you have in console.log(data) ? Try to check then if the column names are matching

Comment: I am getting data from the controller. In console i get the following data  {UserId: 1, Email: "email@gmail.com", PasswordHash: null, PhoneNumber: "", FirstName: "Fn", …}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've had this problem recently.

First off, change your "height" to px, auto, or get rid of it entirely. It's not doing what you think it's doing.

Next, since you have paging, you need to return your data in the following format:

```
{ 
  data: [{your list here}],
  itemsCount: {int}
}
```

It's barely in the documentation, as it's inline and not very obvious. (Bolding mine.)

> loadData is a function returning an array of data or jQuery promise that will be resolved with an array of data (when pageLoading is true instead of object the structure **{ data: [items], itemsCount: [total items count] }** should be returned). Accepts filter parameter including current filter options and paging parameters when

http://js-grid.com/docs/#controller